# Hibernate 6.0.0.Alpha9 cannot resolve c3p0 DriverManagerDataSource

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, c3p0

I have been experimenting with updating Hibernate to `6.0.0 Alpha9` version from Hibernate 5 when I got the message that both `hibernate-core` and `hibernate-c3p0` are being relocated from `org.hibernate` to `org.hibernate.orm`. But as I do that in my Spring MVC configuration class `import com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource;` becomes unresolved. Was it removed from the new version or do I need to use something else instead?

I currently use it as a DataSource for Spring Security and Liquibase:

```
    @Bean(name = "dataSource")
    public DriverManagerDataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource driverManagerDataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        driverManagerDataSource.setDriverClass( dataSourceDriverClass );
        driverManagerDataSource.setJdbcUrl( dataSourceUrl );
        driverManagerDataSource.setUser( dataSourceUsername );
        driverManagerDataSource.setPassword( dataSourcePassword );
        return driverManagerDataSource;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dependency structure seems to have changed i.e. the dependency is not exposed transitively anymore. You will have to add an explicit dependency `api 'com.mchange:c3p0:0.9.5.5'` or

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.mchange</groupId>
  <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
  <version>0.9.5.5</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thank you, that seems to have done the trick. I was sure I had that as a separate c3p0 dependency, which it turns out I did not.